# Переключение между вкладками. WinApi

Tags: winapi, windows, c, visual-studio, c++

Я создал вкладки:

```
hTabCtrl=CreateWindow(WC_TABCONTROL, "", WS_VISIBLE|WS_TABSTOP|WS_CHILD|TCS_FOCUSONBUTTONDOWN ,0,0,0,0,hWnd, (HMENU)ID_TAB, hInst, NULL );

        mOb.SetDefaultFont(hTabCtrl);

            hTabCtrl = GetDlgItem(hWnd, ID_TAB);    
            tci.mask=TCIF_TEXT;
            tci.iImage=-1;

            // Create Three Tabs
            tci.pszText = "Главная";

            TabCtrl_InsertItem(hTabCtrl,0,&tci);

            tci.pszText = "Two";
            TabCtrl_InsertItem(hTabCtrl,1,&tci);
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как программно переключаться между вкладки? Т.е. переключать с первой на вторую вкладку и обратно.

Comment: Я просто уже, как только не пробовал, ни где не могу найти, как это сделать...

Comment: Ничего лучше, чем отправка WM_KEYDOWN с VK_LEFT или VK_RIGHT я в документации не нашел. Попробуйте SendMessage(hTabCtrl, WM_KEYDOWN, VK_RIGHT, 0).

Answer (score 2):

Если поискать на MSDN:
[MSDN TabControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb760550(v=vs.85).aspx)

То можно найти макрос [TabCtrl_SetCurSel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb760684(v=vs.85).aspx) и [TCM_SETCURSEL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb760612(v=vs.85).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Да, действительно, можно  подумать, что такого  вопроса  вовсе и не существует. Как-то он игнорируется, что-ли... А может, надо по принципу обработчика событий его заюзать, предварительно создав вторую вкладку, типа:

```
hTwoTabCtrl = CreateWindow(
    WC_TABCONTROL,
    "",
    WS_VISIBLE | WS_TABSTOP | WS_CHILD | TCS_FOCUSONBUTTONDOWN,
    0, 0, 0, 0,
    hWnd,
    (HMENU)ID_TWOTAB,
    hInst,
    NULL);
```

и потом, при приходе соответствующего сообщения `WM_COMMAND` от Windows,  проверять в обработчике, что там конкретно в слове `wParam`?